# how to extract values from Reduce

Tags: equation-solving

I have received an expression from a Reduce:

```
r = Reduce[{Mod[3 + 2*n, 7] == 0, Mod[1 + 1*n, 3] == 0}, n, Integers];
r

Out[] = C[1] \[Element] Integers && n == 2 + 21 C[1]
```

How can I get values from this? For example:

```
n1 = get_value[r, 0];
n1
n5 = get_value[r, 5];
n5

2
107
```

Comment: It doesn't give me an integer. n1 = r/.C[1]->0 [newline] n1 [newline] Out[] = n == 2. But i wanted to get 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
f[i_Integer] := First@Cases[r /. C[1] -> i, _Integer]
```

Comment: I edited to `f[r_, i_Integer] := First@Cases[r /. C[1] -> i, _Integer]` and that was exactly what i wanted.